# git client seems can not work[Close]

Tags: git, client

I use git client on windows 8.but it seems can't work today!
When we clone a repo from Github, it will create an folder on local and if it sync with the remote repo, the folder will have an green “√” on the folder, also when it doesn't sync with the remote repo,it will have an red warning.

The question is, why in my computer **doesn't** it displays the "√" and the red warning?
I try many git client,eg. msysgit, GitHub for windows, SourceTree.
But all of them can't work.

the following picture can simply display the question I encounter.[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You would need to check if the issue persists when doing a manual clone with msysgit in a command line:

```
git clone https://github.com/user/yourrepo
```

(to be done in a different path than your current local cloned repo)

But note that GitHub experienced some issue yesterday:

> 19:25 UTCWe're investigate errors accessing a small percentage of repositories.

So you also need to check if the issue persists in time, because if it was working before, and nothing else has changed, it should work again.

Comment: Hi,friend!I reinstall the msysgit on my conputer and I clone one repo from my git.it seems doesn't work correctly,it works just like a usual folder and not like a local repo!

Comment: @tudouya do you see a `.git` within that cloned repo folder? Can you copy the command you typed (`git clone xxx`) and the output of that command?

Comment: @tudouya also launch a command-line using `D:\Program files\Git\git-cmd.bat`, and in that new shell, clone the repo in a folder completely different from `D:\Program files\Git\cmd`

Comment: I type the following command and it output the something just as followingh:`**D:\Program Files\Git\cmd>git clone https://github.com/tudouya/MyCode.git**
Cloning into 'MyCode'...
remote: Reusing existing pack: 14, done.
remote: Total 14 (delta 0), reused 0 (delta 0)
Unpacking objects: 100% (14/14), done.
Checking connectivity... done.`

Comment: @tudouya As I said, launch a `git-cmd.bat` session, and try your git clone completely elsewhere.

Comment: ,I think I should tell you my step of installation,maybe you can find some errors on my installation.

Comment: `first,I download the msysgit from the download link of offical site:http://msysgit.github.io/`
`second,I install msysgit step by step`
`third,I clone a repo(also in the folder that not in the msysgit folder`
is there something wrong or is there something more I should do?

Comment: @tudouya I would do the same with http://code.google.com/p/msysgit/downloads/detail?name=PortableGit-1.9.0-preview20140217.7z&can=2&q=, the portable version of msysgit that you can just unzip wherever you want.

Comment: and it seems svn also can not work.I suspect if there is somthing wrong on my system!